# What are some beer festivals other than Oktoberfest?

Tags: alcohol, festivals

Everyone knows about Oktoberfest, I've been to it and it was a blast, but I was wondering what were the other big beer festivals?

Comment: Have you tried google? There is this calendar for example: http://www.beerfestivals.org/ and this wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer_festival

Comment: There are literally thousands of beer festivals around the world, making this question far too broad for our platform. This weekend I'll be going to a local one in Vitória, Brazil.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to add on from what was said before, have you checked out this [article](http://www.wikifestivals.com/blog/best-beer-festivals-world#.U4XHYlVX9pA)? 
It's a list of the top 5 beer festivals in the world. I had never heard of the Qingdao festival in China but it looks excellent! It's in August and apparently they love foreigners there and shower them in beer

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE, but please provide some detail in your answer instead of just linking to external resources!